# How to understand algorithm of generation all the possible symbols sequences using generator function and recursion

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I try to understand the algorithm of the function below and nothing helps me to understand this algorithm, even deep debugging using this https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html. I should notice that i understand iterators and generators for sure, but this made me confused.

Please, explain me how does it work.

The code:

```
def permute(seq):
    """
    This function returns all the possible unique mixes of symbols in sequence

    Example with "xyz" string:
        xyz, xzy, zxy, zyx, yxz, yzx

    :param seq: any sequence
    """

    if not seq:
        yield seq
    else:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i + 1:]
            for x in permute(rest):
                yield seq[i:i + 1] + x


string1 = "hard"
print(*(permute(string1)))  # hard hadr hrad hrda hdar hdra ahrd ahdr arhd ardh adhr adrh rhad rhda rahd radh rdha rdah dhar dhra dahr darh drha drah
```

Comment: What do you understand of it so far?

Comment: I use generators and iterators fluently. But with recursion it racks my brain(recursion always does). If you are asking about this code, i can tell you nothing...

Comment: If you are struggling to even begin to understand, one of the best ways to begin looking at a recursive function is to start at the "base case" and work up - what happens when `permute` is called with an empty string? What happens when it's called with a length 1 string? etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

The function returns generators and in the first `if` statement, it checks whether the parameter `seq` is `False` or `None`. I am going to explain only the first iteration of the length of the parameter and the rest will be same.

```py
for i in range(len(seq)):
    rest = seq[:i] + seq[i + 1:]
```

The possible values of `i` are `0, 1, 2, 3`, if we use your example of `"hard"`.

In the first case, where the value of `i` is `0`, the value of the variable `rest` would be `'' + 'ard'` [`seq[:0] = ''`, `seq[0+1:] or seq[1:] = 'ard'`].

```py
for x in permute(rest):
    yield seq[i:i + 1] + x
```

Here, we find out that `recursion` is being taken place. So, the possible values of `x` (generator) would be `ard adr rad rda dar dra` for our first case [`permute('ard')`]. If you go in depth, you can notice multiple recursions are being taken four times for each case.

Now, if we see the first iteration of the recursion and the output given out, we can notice, it is `'h' + 'ard'`[`seq[i:i + 1]` or further simplification `seq[i:(i+1)]`, then, `seq[0:1] = 'hard'`]. As for second case, it would be `'h' + 'adr' = 'hadr'`.

By further analysis, the following you can see the results of the recursion of first two iterations :

```py
"""The number is the value of i in each recursion"""

 0 # fourth and ending recursion where the string is ''
d 0 # third, 'd'
rd 0 # second, 'rd'
ard 0 # first recursion where second recursion is triggered, seq[0:0+1] is 'h' ('hard')
# You can see a pattern here - ard -> rd -> d

 0
r 1
dr 0
adr 0 # 'hadr'
# ard -> dr -> r
```

So, that's how our first and second strings are obtained. It gets repeated and that's how you get your output.